Standard numbering is not appearing in subsection
In a subsection under a section, I see same numbering pattern as it was in section.
For example, in following example, suppose the section number is 1, then I have

Definition 1.1:

Theorem 1.2:


etc
Then, in subsection number 1.1, I see the same numbering patterns are continuing. For example:

Definition 1.3:

Theorem 1.4:


etc
although it should have been like Definition 1.1.1, Theorem 1.1.2 etc.
Can you please suggest what I should include in the preamble?
I am using the following preamble:
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
%\documentclass [border = .2cm] {standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\topmargin=0.02cm
\textwidth =  17cm
\textheight = 22cm
\baselineskip=11pt
\usepackage{color}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@cite}[2]{\fcolorbox{black}{white}{#1\if@tempswa, #2\fi}}
%\renewcommand*{\@cite}[2]{\fcolorbox{green}{white}{#1, #2}}
\renewcommand*{\@biblabel}[1]{{\fcolorbox{green}{white}{#1}}\hfill}
\makeatother
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.01 pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.01 pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ }
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
%\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{backref=true,
            urlcolor=red,
            linkcolor=red,
            bookmarks=true,
            filecolor=black,
            citecolor=red,
            citebordercolor=green,
            filebordercolor=red,
            linkbordercolor=green
 }

\newtheorem{fig}{figure}[section]
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\newcommand\norm[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}



\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[thm]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}


\newtheorem*{note}{Note}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{subjclassname@2020}{%
    \textup{2020} Mathematics Subject Classification}
\makeatother




\begin{document}
\section{section}
\begin{defn}
content...
\end{defn}
\begin{thm}
content...
\end{thm}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{defn}
content...
\end{defn}
\begin{thm}
content...
\end{thm}

       
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE, please provide MWE from \documentclass to \end{document} as always, I assumed that you are asking about \newtheorem..., if yes, then try with \newtheorem{theorem}[subsection]{Theorem}

@MadyYuvi, I have attached full preamble, it has many things (sorry) but you can check at the bottom, I used \newtheorem.. something like that.

Your code has no output. Please edit it further.

@Stephen, please check again. I have given full details with an example of a section and a subsection.

do you really want the number to increment continuously through a section, but still to include the subsection number? I'd expect either 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 or 1.3 and 1.4. it doesn't make sense to have 1.1.3 and 1.1.4 if there's no 1.1.1 or 1.1.2, does it?

@cfr, thanks. It was my mistake. You are right. But how can get 1.1.1 and 1.1.2?

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]?

@cfr, thanks. I tried it and yes, the numbers are appearing but in that the section numbersing are also of the form 1.0.1 and 1.0.2.

to avoid that you'd have to do something more elaborate, I think. either you  you have to keep changing definitions or you'd need to test the current value of subsection. probably the latter?
